# Can anyone help me to fix the following issues using PHP

Tags: php

1. How to convert to images from blob data from database.

2.then that converted image should stored into the user specifying location in the local machine.

Comment: start by writing some code and then have the code do what you want it to do.

Comment: This may be a good start - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106470/php-convert-a-blob-into-an-image-file#6273415

Comment: Please read [the SO guide on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Questions like the one you posted tend to attract downvotes and are eventually closed.

Comment: Thank you so much @Blinkydamo

Comment: thanks for your concern sir , next time i will do what you suggested @apokryfos

Comment: @LifeTimeProgrammer ,  Sir actullay i found out the solution.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Answer :

```
          $sql="select * from new_table where imageId='9'";
          $result=mysqli_Query($con,$sql);
          $row=mysqli_num_rows($result);
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_Array($result))
              {
                  $image= $row['imageData'];
                  $decoded=base64_decode($image);
                  $name='File2.dwg';
              }
              file_put_contents($path."/".$name, $decoded);
```