# WordPress uploaing blob file

Tags: ajax, wordpress, file, upload, blob

I tried two methods for uploading blob files to WordPress media library.

In first method i tried move blob tmp file to WordPress upload directory with [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.move-uploaded-file.php). Then tried upload this temp file with [media_handle_sideload()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_sideload/) function.

It is blob file that i sent via ajax:

```
array(
    'name'     => '2021-03-26_02-58-09',
    'type'     => 'image/png',
    'tmp_name' => 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\php28D8.tmp',
    'error'    => 0,
    'size'     => 1880058,
);
```

Ajax process:

```
$file       = $_FILES['file'];
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $file['name'] );

$url = $upload_dir['url'] . '/' . $file['name'];
$tmp = download_url( $url );

$file_array = array(
    'name'     => basename( $url ),
    'tmp_name' => $tmp,
);

$id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, 0 );

var_dump( $id );
```

But it returns `Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons` error.

So i tried this with [wp_insert_attachment()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_attachment/) function. It is uploading file but without image extension (.jpg, .png) and it is not generating additional image sizes. Here is what i tried:

```
$file       = $_FILES['file'];
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $file['name'] );

$id = wp_insert_attachment(
    array(
        'guid'           => $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $file['name'],
        'post_mime_type' => $file['type'],
        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $file['name'] ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    ),
    $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $file['name']
);

var_dump( $id );
```

Comment: You can convert blob file to image and the upload see here [Php : Convert a blob into an image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106470/php-convert-a-blob-into-an-image-file)

Comment: Can you suggest any WordPress way? Because it is for my WordPress plugin and it will be used by thousand users. So GD, iMagick or other extensions may not have been installed on users' server.